# Why does the output of PIL look different to matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am doing some image processing in Python. I was originally using PIL to display my image but the output didn't look right to me so I used matplotlib instead and that seems to result in the output I was expecting. Below I have pasted screenshots of the PIL image and the matplotlib image, I was just wondering if anyone could explain why the two libraries output such different images.

[image]

PIL image

```
#PIL CODE
#final_patch is a tensor of shape (1,3,288,384)

from torchvision import transforms
toPIL = transforms.ToPILImage()
display(toPIL(final_patch.squeeze()))
```

[image]

matplotlib image

```
#matplotlib CODE
#final_patch is a tensor of shape (1,3,288,384)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(final_patch.squeeze().detach().permute(1,2,0))
plt.axis("off")
```

Any answers to help me understand why the two outputs look different would be greatly appreciated.

ps. Don't worry about the image being blue, I am using OpenCV to load it in so the color channels are ordered BGR right now.

Comment: It's probably related to the `dtype` and range of `final_patch`. What is the `dtype`? What are the minimum and maximum values?

Comment: @Rotem, the dtype is float32, the max value is: 1.2937 and the min value is: -0.6312

Comment: Convert the range to [0, 1] before displaying.

Comment: that worked, thanks, the only thing is that the image now looks like it had its opacity reduced. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: use `np.clip()` or whatever you have to (you didn't tag pytorch or torchvision)

Comment: Just look into the docs for the two display functions to learn how they convert floating point values to intensities on the screen.